# Why doesn't PHP allow classes have class and instance members with the same name?

Tags: php, oop

```
class Example {
   # Instance member 
   private $member;
   # Class member
   private static $member;
}
```

This would result in the following error:

> Cannot redeclare Example::$member in ...

Since class and instance members live in different scopes, I find the error a bit unexpected and I wonder about the motivation behind it.

p.s. Are there other OO languages that have the same ristriction?

Comment: Do you have another class accidentally named Example? If not, do you have any more code you can post to have a look at?

Comment: Where else is `$class_member` declared?

Comment: huh? I don't get it, I see no reason why that code would throw an error.

Comment: The example was not correct. I apologize.

Comment: Why do you want to create this confusing situation?

Comment: I get you, yes you cant declare variables like that. The two items need unique names.

Comment: @MarkBaker, why do you assume that I want to?

Comment: @Emanuil - the fact that you're trying it... I know you can argue that you're just testing the limits of the language; but I'd counter-argue that the only people who can answer your question (why isn't it allowed?) are the designers/developers of PHP itself, so why not ask them directly rather than assume that we can read their minds

Comment: @MarkBaker, I have an instance method that does an action called "foo" and, when it does it, it takes into consideration the state of the variables of the instance. In the same class, I want to have a class method that also does an action called "foo", but instead of the instance scope, I want it to use the scope of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access static functions with `$this->name()` too, ugly as it may seem. Maybe that is one reason.

Comment: This is quite peculiar. It does, however, throw an exception if you try this with variables (as opposed to methods).

Answer (score 1):

You can dig it using [reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php)

If you get list of properties, it will have additional flags like `isStatic`. So basically properties must be unique regardless of if they're static of not.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is simple: static and instance members with the same name are ambiguous.

For example, imagine:

```
class Example {
   # Instance member 
   private $member;
   # Class member
   private static $member;

   public function AmbiguousCaller() {
       //What should be returned?
       return get_class_vars(get_class($this));
   }
}
```

Comment: I imagined it and then I imagined another thing - a PHP that has both `get_class_vars` and `get_instance_vars`. I liked the later better.

Comment: @EmanuilRusev This was just an example. Reflection is another good reason.